# should the intelligent pointer be used in basic data structure, e.g. doubly linked list, binary tree?

Tags: c++, c++11

For the basic data structures, for instance,
Doubly linked list has something like `Node * next`, `Node * prev`;
Binary Tree has something like `Node * left`, `Node * right`;
What are the pros. and cons. by using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to replace above `Node *`?
Are there any well-known open source projects in this way?

Comment: The "pros and cons" are the direct result of how smart pointers work. Understanding how smart pointers work makes it clear whether or not using them is a good idea. For example, they'll never work with a doubly-linked list. Everyone who understands what `shared_ptr`s and `unique_ptr`s are, and how they work, don't need anyone else to tell them not to use them, since it's clear why they'll never work with doubly-linked lists, for their own individual reasons. So, it's more productive to focus on learning and understanding them, and challenge yourself to figure out the pros and cons yourself.

Comment: I'm afraid not so "direct". Doubly linked list can be implemented with ```next``` as ```unique_ptr``` but ```prev``` as raw pointer. When destryoing the head node, it will destroy the whole list. This is the good thing. But the bad thing is, there could be too many layers of recusive function call of the destruction of unique_ptr so that the stack could be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer part of my own question by myself.
Doubly-Linked List can be implemented by treating `next` as `unique_ptr` and `prev` as raw pointer. The last node's `next` should not point to head node but should be `unique_ptr<T>()`.

1. One pros. is, we don't need to worry about when the List will be destructed. It will manage itself when the life cycle of head node is done. When that happens, the whole List will be destructed one node afte another from the head node. It's automated.
2. One cons. is, the code is more complex.
3. Another cons. is, if there are too many nodes in the List, the destructing of the List will cause segment fault, as there are too many layers of recursive destructor of the `unique_ptr`. My own experience is, when there are about 65400+ nodes, the core dump will happen.

About using `shared_ptr`, I guess the cons. could be easy to encounter circular reference. I did not implement it yet.

About binary tree, um..., just feel that's not a good idea to use intelligent pointer to replace `Node * left` and/or `Node * right`.

So, personally, the conclusion is, it could be better to not using intelligent pointer in basic data structure. Welcome any comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer, it's more a question. (I don't have enough "karma" to leave comments, sorry).
I've heard that `new` keyword will be removed in `C++23`, and it's already deprecated for the `C++20`, so how we will implement a double-linked list, as usage of smart pointer not fully fit here (based on @Finix answer) and `new` will be deprecated?

Comment: That story was an april fools joke in 2018. The `new` and `delete` keywords are not deprecated and will not be removed.

Comment: ahaha, damn, thank you! I've read it somewhere recently, and was thinking of it all last days. :)